# concat sql query > show same column in 2 differents columns according to where clause

Tags: sql, union, concatenation

I wish to make a connection between two sql queries showing the same field in two different column in a "WHERE" clause as shown in the following example:

**Query n° 1 :**

```
SELECT  COUNT([ID]) AS SOCIETE_1,
        CAST([Créé le] AS date) AS DateCreated
FROM [MFilesCloudReport].[dbo].[Document]
WHERE [Société_ID] = 1
GROUP BY CAST([Créé le] AS date)
ORDER BY CAST([Créé le] AS date)
```

--> **Result n° 1 :**

```
SOCIETE_1   DateCreated
-----------------------------------
142     |   2013-01-17
148     |   2013-01-21
88      |   2013-01-23
188     |   2013-01-25
187     |   2013-01-29
124     |   2013-01-31
```

**Query n° 2 :**

```
SELECT  COUNT([ID]) AS SOCIETE_2,
    CAST([Créé le] AS date) AS DateCreated
FROM [MFilesCloudReport].[dbo].[Document]
WHERE [Société_ID] = 2
GROUP BY CAST([Créé le] AS date)
ORDER BY CAST([Créé le] AS date)
```

--> **Result n° 2 :**

```
SOCIETE_2   DateCreated
-----------------------------------
18      |   2013-01-17
73      |   2013-01-21
75      |   2013-01-23
1       |   2013-01-24
48      |   2013-01-25
80      |   2013-01-29
43      |   2013-01-31
```

The expected result would be this one:

```
SOCIETE_1     SOCIETE_2     TOTAL       DateCreated
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
142         |   18      |   160     |   2013-01-17
148         |   73      |   221     |   2013-01-21
88          |   75      |   163     |   2013-01-23
0           |   1       |   1       |   2013-01-24
188         |   48      |   236     |   2013-01-25
187         |   80      |   267     |   2013-01-29
124         |   43      |   167     |   2013-01-31
```

Thank you in advance for your help and good day to you all.

Comment: ***WHAT*** RDBMS is this for? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? Postgres? Informix? Interbase? Something else??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(case when [Société_ID] = 1 then [ID] end) AS SOCIETE_1,
        COUNT(case when [Société_ID] = 2 then [ID] end) AS SOCIETE_2,
        COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
        CAST([Créé le] AS date) AS DateCreated
FROM [MFilesCloudReport].[dbo].[Document]
GROUP BY CAST([Créé le] AS date)
ORDER BY CAST([Créé le] AS date)
```

Comment: @JW yes, I agree, but depends on exactly what is necessary to show in the `TOTAL` column.

Comment: It works perfectly. A great thank for you, I can apply now this method to many query :)

Thank you for your help and thank to the community :)